# zurb foundation 6 on rails 4 works locally but not on dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, dokku

I have a rails app with foundation 6 gem that renders well locally, but as soon that I push to a dokku server, the layout is not rendered.

On the chrome devlopper console I find the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

#CMS
gem 'comfortable_mexican_sofa', '~> 1.12.0'
gem 'comfy_blog', '~> 1.12.0'
#foundation
gem 'foundation_rails_helper'
gem 'foundation-rails', github: "zurb/foundation-rails"
gem 'foundation-icons-sass-rails'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
gem 'puma'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

ruby "2.2.2"
```

EDIT:
I've realised that locally the application.erb.html is inserted, but on dokku it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assets are precompiled. In the production environment 'rake assets:precompile' has to run through before the rails server is started.

Comment: Dear gugl, I've done that. I've realised now that the problem lies somewhere else. I'm using Comfy Mexican Sofa, and with SQLite application.html.erb is included correctly (both in development and production), but as soon as I switch to PostgresQL this is not the case anymore and I'm left with the layout I've entered in Comfy.